# Docker Compose up exiting with error code 2

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker, and I am currently learning it for my last class in school. I keep getting the following error any time I try to run docker compose up. My class mates couldn't help me and my professor hasn't responded to me in a week so I turning here.

The CL output:

```
lafs-db   | {"t":{"$date":"2022-11-12T12:20:32.867+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"lsidTTLIndex","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
lafs-api  | /bin/sh: 1: [: missing ]
lafs-api exited with code 0
lafs-api exited with code 2
lafs-api exited with code 2
lafs-api exited with code 2
```

Here is my docker file.

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server/server.js" ] 
# CMD npm run start
```

and here is my docker compose file.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  # REST API running on Node JS container
  app:
    container_name: lafs-api
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    # link this container to the Mongo DB container
    links:
      - mongo
    # pass in environment variables for database host and name
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mongo
      - DB_NAME=lafs-db
  # Mongo DB storage container
  mongo:
    container_name: lafs-db
    image: "mongo:4"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
# Attach the external network to these containers
networks:
  default:
  external:
    name: lafs-net
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you double-check that the `CMD` in your Dockerfile uses "normal" punctuation; plain ASCII spaces, "straight" quotes, and so on?  It looks okay as you've written it, but the error you're quoting looks like the symptom where Docker failed to parse it as a JSON array and so is falling back to running it as a shell command.

Comment: Yeah all the punctuation is normal, I've checked it multiple times because that's what I originally thought it was too.